# Translucency amount control

Tags: shaders

I have created a plant with leaves. I have used a leaf texture to with a translucent shader . But I want to be able to control the amount of translucency  . Which node can I use to achieve control of translucency?

Answer (score 1):

In Cycles you need to add the Mix Shader and adjust its Factor value. When set to 0.5 (the default) it gives equal share to Translucent and Diffuse BSDF.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually better to use the principled shader for a plant. After that, you can add mix shader, and mix with Translucent shader. Also, you can use a texture for translucency, which you plug in the fac part of the mix shader. This way, you achieve a Translucency that is different in different parts of the leaves. I usually do all these textures from a single color texture, where the translucent shader gets a more saturated version, and the mixing factor is also the same texture with tweaked brightness and contrast.